# Using variable from another script (inter-file function closure)

Tags: r

I have script main.R, where I create inv_cov_mat variable. I later load metrics.R and  use it to calculate function value (I use it as kind of inter-script function closure). I get error "object 'inv_cov_mat' not found". My code:

main.R:

```
knn <- function(...)
{
  # some code
  source("./source/metrics.R")
  if (metric == "mahalanobis")
    inv_cov_mat <- solve(cov(training_set))
  # other code
  # calculate distance in given metric between current vector and every row vector from training set matrix
  distances <- apply(training_set, 1, metric, vec2=curr_vec) # error
```

metrics.R:

```
mahalanobis <- function(vec1, vec2)
{
  diff <- vec1 - vec2
  sqrt(t(diff) %*% inv_cov_mat %*% diff)
}
```

Comment: Can you add a new parameter in `mahalanobis to pass the inv_cov_mat.  Also, what is `training_set`?

Comment: I could, although because I choose metric function with match.fun(fun_as_string) I would have to create nested if constructions to use metrics that require things beside 2 vectors (e. g. Mahalanobis, standarized Euclidean). That would make my code both slower, uglier and harder to maintain.

Comment: Or you may have to pass the environment so that the function would check for the object in the correct env.  Something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002811/accessing-variables-in-a-function-within-a-function)

Comment: I edited my question to answer your question about training_set. About environment - I tried using ```get("inv_cov_mat", env=parent.frame(), inherits=TRUE)``` in mahalanobis function, but it can't find it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've found simple, even if not elegant answer: use inv_cov_mat as global variable, not inside knn function. Then other scripts can see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but if I understand you correctly---you have a character string identifying the metric you want to use, and a function with the same name. So you should be able to use `get` to retrieve the function based on the name.

```r
metric == "mahalanobis"
metric.fun = get(metric)
distances <- apply(training_set, 1, metric.fun, vec2=curr_vec)
```

That said, there are probably better ways to organize your code that would avoid this problem entirely, e.g. create a named list of functions for accessing metrics.

**EDIT** regarding the issue of `inv_cov_mat`, either pass it as an argument to your metric function or use `get` *inside* that function to access variables from the parent environment using the `envir` argument. Passing the variable as an argument to your metric function is definitely the better and cleaner approach.

Comment: I get function properly with match.fun, that's no problem, I just have problems with getting ```inv_cov_mat``` inside that metric function. Passing variable is, as I have described previously in comment, quite a bad idea in my code structure (though I would do it normally, it's just the matter of existing code). As I've also written in last comment, get function does not work for some reason, but global variable in main.R works.